# SQL set check constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a problem with setting check constrain. I have table Policy where primary key is set on `(Policy_id, History_id)` + additional columns and table Report which have `Policy_id` and some additional columns.

**How can I set check constraint statement on Report table to check if policy_id exists in Policy table?**

I cannot use foreign key constrain because Report do not have history_id column

Report cannot contain record with `Policy_id` if it do not exists in Policy table and hence, cannot perform insert into Report

Comment: You can write a function that accepts a Policy_id and checks to see if it exists in the Policy table.

Answer (score 0):

If the `Policy_id` and `History_id` are a composite primary key then the foreign key on the referencing table must also hold the both columns.

If you really need to check just for one of them (the `policy_id`) I guess you'd have to do it manually which is not a good idea.

It would be better if the `Report` table would have 2 foreign keys and both the `policy_id` and `history_id` would be a single primary keys.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a separate table just for the purposes of this foreign key constraint and then use triggers to maintain this data:

```
CREATE TABLE ExistingPolicies (
    PolicyID int not null,
    PolicyCount int not null,
    constraint PK_ExistingPolicies PRIMARY KEY (PolicyID)
```

)

And then the triggers:

```
CREATE TRIGGER T_Policy_I
on Policy
instead of insert
as
     ;With totals as (
         select PolicyID,COUNT(*) as cnt from inserted
         group by PolicyID
     )
     merge into ExistingPolicies t
     using totals s
     on
        t.PolicyID = s.PolicyID
     when matched then update set PolicyCount = PolicyCount + s.cnt
     when not matched then insert (PolicyID,PolicyCount) values (s.PolicyID,s.cnt);
go
CREATE TRIGGER T_Policy_D
on Policy
instead of delete
as
     ;With totals as (
         select PolicyID,COUNT(*) as cnt from deleted
         group by PolicyID
     )
     merge into ExistingPolicies t
     using totals s
     on
        t.PolicyID = s.PolicyID
     when matched and t.PolicyCount = s.cnt then delete
     when matched then update set PolicyCount = PolicyCount - s.cnt;
go
CREATE TRIGGER T_Policy_U
on Policy
instead of update
as
     ;With totals as (
         select PolicyID,SUM(cnt) as cnt
         from
            (select PolicyID,1 as cnt from inserted
             union all
             select PolicyID,-1 as cnt from deleted
             ) t
         group by PolicyID
     )
     merge into ExistingPolicies t
     using totals s
     on
        t.PolicyID = s.PolicyID
     when matched and t.PolicyCount = -s.cnt then delete
     when matched then update set PolicyCount = PolicyCount + s.cnt
     when not matched then insert (PolicyID,PolicyCount) values (s.PolicyID,s.cnt);
go
```

(Code not tested but should be close to correct)

Answer (score 0):

I think using a check constraint is a fine idea here.

Write a function that accepts Policy_id as a parameter, and does a query to check if the policy exists in the Policy table, and returns a simple 1 (exists) or 0 (does not exist).

Then set your check constraint on your Report Table to `dbo.MyFunction(Policy_Id)=1`

That's it.